# Understanding an SML type fn (f,g,x) => g(f(x)) or similar

Tags: sml, smlnj

Ok, sorry in advance this probably is repost but I spent a good 30 minutes searching stackoverflow and couldn't find something similar enough to understand. Basically, I don't understand why

```
fn (f,g,x) => g(f(x))
```

gives the type

```
(’a -> ’b)*(’b -> ’c)*’a -> ’c
```

from my understanding it should start with

```
'a * 'b * 'c...
```

But this is evidently wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it all starts with `'a * 'b * 'c`, where `f : 'a`, `g : 'b`, `x : 'c` but then the type inference mechanism sees that `f` is applied `x`, so
so it concludes that the function `f : 'd -> 'e` (i.e. `'b = 'd -> 'e`). Also, the type of `x` must comply with `f`'s input type, thus `'d = 'c` and `f : 'c -> 'e`.

Furthermore, `g` is a function as well, so `'b = 'y -> 'z` and it's easy to see that `f`'s output type must be equal to `g`'s input type, which gives us the following type equation `'y = 'e`.

We have `x : 'c`, `f : 'c -> 'e`, `g : 'e -> 'z`. Concrete variable names don't matter and we can rename them like so:

```
'c -> 'a
'e -> 'b
'z -> 'c
```

That gives as `x : 'a`, `f : 'a -> 'b`, and `g : 'b -> 'c`

Since `fn (f,g,x)` takes a triple as its input, it must have the type

```
<type of f> * <type of g> * <type of x> -> <output type of g>
```

Expanding the above semi-formal description we get

```
('a -> 'b) * ('b -> 'c) * a' -> 'c
```

Comment: Thanks! helped a lot  really appreciate it.